# Is there any other way besides MAPI to know two different email addresses belong to one Outlook account?

Tags: c++, email, outlook, mapi

I am trying to integrate my application with Outlook. I have referred to [Integrating IM applications with Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/integrating-im-applications-with-office).

I met an issue when an Outlook/Office account has two different email addresses, Outlook will call the `IContactManager.GetContactByUri()` API twice with the two email addresses. Because I don't know the two email addresses belongs to one account, I will return different property values of the two emails to Outlook, which finally lead to Outlook showing an unexpected state on the contact page.

For example, one Outlook account `Glider` has two email addresses `glider123@xxx.com` and `gliderABC@xxx.com`. In my application, account `glider123@gmail.com` is in the presence state of busy, while `gliderABC@xxx.com` is in the presence state of free.

Because I don't know `glider123@xxx.com` and `gliderABC@xxx.com` belong to one Outlook account `Glider`, when Outlook calls the `GetContactByUri()` API, I will create two `IContact` instances on my local, and they will return different presence state values to Outlook. Finally, on the contact page of `Glider` in Outlook, its presence state is free.

I know MAPI can solve this, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an Exchange account, multiple proxy addresses are stored in the `PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101F`), which can be accessed in Outlook Object Model using `AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`.